# how can i change the ip evry X hours on CentOS 6.6?

Tags: iptables, centos6

So I have a server running CentOS6, and have 5 IP addresses registered to the server. I'd like to rotate through the 5 IPs every 2 hours using a different one. What would my best approach be to do this?
i found that it's possible withe the iptables firewall but i dont know how to make it

```
# iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 -j SNAT --to-source 202.XXX.XX.2
```

if there is any other way to change the ip i'll be thankfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `statistic` module is not what you're looking for. You should use `iptables`'s `time` module, as follows:

```
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 00:00:00 --timestop 01:59:59 -j ACTION-1
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 02:00:00 --timestop 03:59:59 -j ACTION-2
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 04:00:00 --timestop 05:59:59 -j ACTION-3
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 06:00:00 --timestop 07:59:59 -j ACTION-4
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 08:00:00 --timestop 09:59:59 -j ACTION-5
iptables RULE -m time --timestart 10:00:00 --timestop 11:59:59 -j ACTION-1
```

... and so on ...

More information about the `time` module, can be found in [`iptables-extensions` man page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html).

---

**EDIT:** For example, an appropriate rule could look like:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -o eth0 -m state --state NEW -m time --timestart 00:00:00 --timestop 01:59:59 -j SNAT --to-source 202.XXX.XX.2
```

Comment: can u tell me with what do i have to replace that ACTION-1

and where ?